# Changing the position of the limits in the declared operators

Tags: math-operators, integral

I use the `concrete` headset in one of my documents. In doing so, I have a need to map the surface integral over a closed surface. Unfortunately, I found that the `esint` package changes the font of the mathematical operators. For this reason I had the idea to "draw" my own `\oiint` operator. However, I had a problem in matching the position of the signature of the limits of this operator with the already existing integral operators (see figure below).

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to eliminate this displacement?

Also ideally, of course, I would like to know how you can change the content of the defined operator in the document depending on the loaded packages. For example, so that the `\oiint` operator works according to one algorithm if the `concrete` package is loaded, or otherwise takes an implementation from the `esint` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
    
\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{tikz}


\def\oiint{\operatornamewithlimits{%
        \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
                        \node (center) at (0,0) {$\displaystyle %
                        \kern0.25pt%
                        \int%
                        \kern-4.2pt%
                        \int$};%
                        \draw[line width=0.025cm] circle [radius = 0.2 cm];%
                        \end{tikzpicture}}}}%
        {\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
                        \node (center) at (0,0) {$\kern0.3pt%
                            \int%
                            \kern-4.75pt%
                            \int$};%
                        \draw[line width=0.02cm] ellipse (0.175 cm and 0.1 cm);%
                        \end{tikzpicture}}}}%
        {\text{A}}%
        {\text{A}}}}


\begin{document}

$$\oiint\limits_{\Gamma}{\vv{A} \,d \vv{S}}%
\quad %
\iint\limits_{\Gamma}{\vv{A} \,d \vv{S}}$$

$$\oiint\limits_{\partial V}{\vv{F} \, d\vv{S}} = \iiint\limits_{V}{\mathrm{div}{\vv{F}} \, dV}$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[inner sep=0pt]` to the first `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
    
\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{tikz}


\def\oiint{\operatornamewithlimits{%
        \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]%
                        \node (center) at (0,0) {$\displaystyle %
                        \kern0.25pt%
                        \int%
                        \kern-4.2pt%
                        \int$};%
                        \draw[line width=0.025cm] circle [radius = 0.2 cm];%
                        \end{tikzpicture}}}}%
        {\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
                        \node (center) at (0,0) {$\kern0.3pt%
                            \int%
                            \kern-4.75pt%
                            \int$};%
                        \draw[line width=0.02cm] ellipse (0.175 cm and 0.1 cm);%
                        \end{tikzpicture}}}}%
        {\text{A}}%
        {\text{A}}}}


\begin{document}

$$\oiint\limits_{\Gamma}{\vv{A} \,d \vv{S}}%
\quad %
\iint\limits_{\Gamma}{\vv{A} \,d \vv{S}}$$

$$\oiint\limits_{\partial V}{\vv{F} \, d\vv{S}} = \iiint\limits_{V}{\mathrm{div}{\vv{F}} \, dV}$$

\end{document}
```

[image]